# Two spinner resets each other when selected (android)

Tags: android, spinner

In my android app I have 2 spinners e.g. one for selecting fruit and another for selecting flower.

The requirement is like this when I select fruit then the flower must be reset and vise-versa. In short only one can be selected either fruit or flower.

Then I have API call after the selection...

For reset I am using spinner.setSelection(0) method which creating some kind of redundancy in call, since setSelection method automatically calls onItemSelectedListener.

Here is my code:-

```
spnFruit.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(flower) {
                return;
            }

            Log.e("TYPE", "Fruit");
            fruit = true;
            spnFlower.setSelection(0);
            fruit = false;

            // API call
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    spnFlower.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            if(fruit) {
                return;
            }

            Log.e("TYPE", "Flower");
            flower = true;
            spnFruit.setSelection(0);
            flower = false;

            // API call
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });
```

Where fruit and flower are the boolean values.

Please tell my gusy where I am wrong?

Comment: add your full code where you set the spinner adapter

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the same issue. I overcome with that by calling 
[public void setSelection (int position, boolean animate)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSpinner.html#setSelection(int,%20boolean);)

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner.setSelection(0, false);
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(callback);
```

After setting false it won't call `OnItemSelectedListener` callback.